# Encrypt a USB flash drive, open without additonal software

Tags: usb-flash-drive, disk-encryption

Hey, I want to encrypt a USB flash drive, I know TrueCrypt is excellent, but I want to be able to open it on any computer without installing additional software.
Thanks

Comment: You need a flash drive with an unencrypted partition for the decryption software.

Comment: Eventually I extracted TrueCrypt on the flash drive, it does not require an installation and can be run from any computed (although I would need a different version for Linux)

Comment: I come from an older tradition in which installation of software simply meant copying it to the computer. But I know where you're coming from -- these days installing software usually mean going through a complex installation process. Is TrueCrypt actually *on* the flash drive, so it goes wherever the flash drive goes?

Comment: Yeah, it's just outside of the encrypted volume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [SecurStick](http://www.withopf.com/tools/securstick/) (page only available in German, Google translation [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://www.withopf.com/tools/securstick/&langpair=de%7Cen)).

> SecurStick for Windows,
>   Mac OS X and Linux [...] allows you to encrypt data on USB
>   sticks and other media. [...] There is no
>   installation of software or drivers
>   required.

[image]

Comment: What if I want to add data later, does it provide a tool to encrypt data I add on the fly, or do I need to repeat the process?

Comment: You have to create the safe zone only once. According to another picture (http://www.zhacks.com/images/securstick-safe-zone-encryption.png) you can just copy file to the safe zone.

Comment: This is a bit complicated to do every time you add files.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. You have to create the safe zone only ONCE. Then, after pluggin in your USB drive, you have to login through the webinterface, connect to `127.0.0.1/X` or mount the drive and drop files. Apart from this I didn't even know that encrypting a USB drive without additional software is possible. So either you try `SecurStick` and see if it suits you OR use additional software.